# Working with Hamletfile's Q Exp return value

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, hamlet

Given this last line in [my Haskell learning project](https://github.com/leonstafford/mini_haskell_webapp):

```
writeText $ TL.toStrict (renderHtml $(hamletFile "fileList.hamlet"))
```

I would like to convert the output from `hamletFile`'s [signature](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2010/08/typesafe-runtime-hamlet) of:

```
FilePath -> Q Exp
```

into the Html type expected by the `renderHtml` function.

*Big chance I'm completely wrong in my above assertions of what I'm currently doing!

Comment: `Q` is a template haskell type. You'd need to expand it somehow I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close to getting this working. As Bartek and MathematicalOrchid are both saying, `hamletFile "fileList.hamlet"` has type `Q Exp`, which means "GHC can run this to generate an expression." By wrapping it in `$(...)`, you're saying, "GHC, please generate an expression." The next question you need to ask it: what's the type of this generated expression?

You can get more information in the [shakespeare chapter of the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates), but the expression will have type:

```
(url -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text) -> Html
```

Which basically means "tell me how to turn a URL and some query string parameters into text, and I'll give you some HTML." If you're not using any type-safe URLs in your template, you can simply provide `undefined` (or switch to using `shamletFile`, see the chapter for more information).

Once you provide the URL rendering function, you can use `renderHtml` to get your lazy strict and continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the expression `$(hamletFile "fileList.hamlet")` means "execute this function call at compile-time to generate from Haskell source code". What exact code it generates I don't know.

I don't know Hamlet, but there's probably some way of asking it to do this translation at run-time instead of compile-time — and that's probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answers above and some outside assistance, my working code became:

`writeText $ TL.toStrict (renderHtml ($(hamletFile "fileList.hamlet") "HTML"))`

And required adding `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}` to the top of the script (something to do with intricacies of working with Template Haskell, it seems).